# Tensorflow ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'MXHbacc3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I tried to build artificial neural network,
but it's not working.
How do I do it?

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=12, input_dim=4, init='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

__main__:1: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(input_dim=4, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="normal", units=12)`

model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, init='normal', activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=100, verbose=0)
```

```
2019-09-25 22:11:17.983801: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2721, in __call__
    return self._legacy_call(inputs)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2693, in _legacy_call
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1097, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/Users/kimsohyeon/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'MXHbacc3'
```

Then, Is it a good idea to delete the conda virtual environment and reinstall new one?

```
>>> tf.__version__
'1.5.0
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to read, code and error should be on different place.

Comment: But the problem ia most likely about your data and nothing to do with what shown here.

Comment: Deleting virtual environment won't do much.